# Android Studio Extended Controls Location Google Maps Not Loading

Tags: android, android-studio

Has anyone experience this before? My emulator doesn't load the Google maps UI in extended control. [image: SCREENSHOT]

I tried reinstalling to latest version and reinstall AVDs but won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine now. There was a breaking change to the Google Maps javascript API. So It was Problem

Comment: It's working on my end now too. Thank you for updating me! :)